# Leaflet Slider Playback:

Tags: javascript, slider, leaflet

I have an array of locations and timestamps. I am trying to make a slider that each slider's tick base on each location change. 
I have tried to modify [Leaflet playback](https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback) but I have no luck. The leaflet playback plugin's slider slides on every 25ms which doesn't do what I am trying to do.

Comment: pls add a fiddle how you want to do it

Comment: @Manuel The leaflet playback is pretty much what I am trying to modify. I dont know how to modify it or make it works the way I described. As you can see in the playback, the slider is moving every 25ms changed. I want it change on position not on every 25ms.